# Google Anthos setup with VMware on premise

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I am working on proof of value implementation for Anthos on premise. I went through the VSphere requirements and found a standard requirement stack on the docs which frankly is Little high (on price n size) to implement just a concept.

1. Is there a way to create a small setup like on a single VM (performance is not the concern) for Anthos on Premise.
2. Is it mandatory to have VCenter for this setup as the license cost is also a concern.

Basically I am interested in setting up a 4 core 32 GB machine with Anthos.
Major reason for using Anthos is to use google services with ready GKE implementation that scales in heterogeneous environment.
There are other kubernetes wrappers and container orchestration platforms like Platform9 and Openshift, but they are next comparison steps to Anthos.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find from the research I have done, the only way for you to try out small scale anthos would be to use the sample deployment [1]. This would be a small scale anthos deployment, not gke on prem, but gke on prem doesn't have a demo so this would be the only option for demo purposes I can suggest.

I have also searched for documentation in regards to vSphere and it is clear that vSphere is required [2]. I have not found anything else suggesting that its possible to not use vsphere.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/anthos/docs/setup/overview#sample_deployment
[2] https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/on-prem/how-to/vsphere-requirements-basic

Answer (score 0):

As of Anthos on VMware version 1.9, the documentation states that a demonstration installation is possible using a single ESXi host with 8 CPUs, 40GB RAM and 450GB of storage[1].

vSphere is also currently a requirement at this version.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/on-prem/1.9/how-to/vsphere-requirements#minimum-hardware-requirements-for-demonstration-purposes